# Unable to change location of chart legend without getting an error

Tags: excel, vba

I have search the site and have a couple of examples but both generate errors.  is it possible to move the legend within the With cht/End with section of the code?

```
.SetElement (msoElementLegendBottom)
```

---

```
Sub ChartTest()

    Dim cht As Object

    Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=300, Width:=350, Top:=300, Height:=300)

    With cht

        .Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B13"), PlotBy:=xlColumns
        .Chart.Type = 3

         .SetElement (msoElementLegendBottom)
    End With 


End Sub
```

Comment: I must have missed the end with what coping, the error is " Object does not support this property or method"

Comment: `.Chart.SetElement` maybe, if I'm reading the docs right? (If so you could just do `With cht.Chart` and remove the other instances of `.Chart` in the previous two lines).

Comment: That worked BigBen. I am slowly getting the hang of this stuff.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the method is [`Chart.SetElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.chart.setelement):

Easiest fix is just to change to `With cht.Chart` and remove the instances of `.Chart` in the previous two lines:

```
With cht.Chart
    .SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B13"), PlotBy:=xlColumns
    .Type = 3

     .SetElement msoElementLegendBottom
End With
```